# Jira передать с Java Json со спец символами

Tags: java, json

Всем привет. Передаю по Jira api json для создания нового таска. Строку динамически беру из бд, и там почти всегда есть куча всяких спецсимволов, что выдает еррор json

```
{"errorMessages":["Illegal unquoted character
```

пример строки такоЙ:

```
" ; "msisdn"= 380<!^d+${9}>
мин/макс - 1//9
номер - 38092

"
```

строка формирования строки джейсона (message - строка из бд):

```
String createIssueData = "{\"fields\":{\"project\":{\"key\":\"*****\"},\"summary\":\""+subject+"\"" +
                    ",  \"description\": \""+message+"\",\"priority\":{\"name\":\"Trivial\"},\"issuetype\":{\"name\":\"New Feature\"}}}";
```

Подскажите как бы передать это все дело. Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не склеивайте json руками, используйте инструменты, которые гарантируют вам экранирование спецсимволов, например [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs) или [gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

В самом простом варианте, вы складываете ключи и значения в Map, который сериализуете в JSON-строку.

```
String subject = "subj";
String message = "msg";

Map fields = new HashMap();
fields.put("project", Collections.singletonMap("key", "*****"));
fields.put("summary", subject);
fields.put("description", message);
fields.put("priority", Collections.singletonMap("name", "Trivial"));
fields.put("issuetype", Collections.singletonMap("name", "New Feature"));

Map request = Collections.singletonMap("name", fields);


ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request);
```

В переменной `json` вы получите:

```
{"name":{"summary":"subj","project":{"key":"*****"},"issuetype":{"name":"New Feature"},"priority":{"name":"Trivial"},"description":"msg"}}
```

---

Более зрелое решение - создать DTO-классы, описывающие поля вашего JSON-сообщения и сериализовывать его. Это позволит проверять корректность передаваемых значений и избавит от необходимости работать с JSON через строковые ключи.

Опять-таки, для Jackson будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
public class Request {

    @JsonProperty("requestFields")
    private RequestFields requestFields;

    public Request(RequestFields requestFields) {
        this.requestFields = requestFields;
    }

    //  геттеры и сеттеры

    public static class RequestFields {
        @JsonProperty("project")
        private RequestProject project;
        @JsonProperty("summary")
        private String summary;
        @JsonProperty("description")
        private String description;
        @JsonProperty("priority")
        private RequestPriority priority;
        @JsonProperty("issuetype")
        private RequestIssueType issuetype;

        public RequestFields(RequestProject project, String summary, String description, RequestPriority priority, RequestIssueType issuetype) {
            this.project = project;
            this.summary = summary;
            this.description = description;
            this.priority = priority;
            this.issuetype = issuetype;
        }

        //  геттеры и сеттеры
    }

    public static class RequestProject {
        @JsonProperty("key")
        private String key;

        public RequestProject(String key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        //  геттеры и сеттеры
    }

    public static class RequestPriority {
        @JsonProperty("name")
        private String name;

        public RequestPriority(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        //  геттеры и сеттеры
    }

    public static class RequestIssueType {
        @JsonProperty("name")
        private String name;

        public RequestIssueType(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        //  геттеры и сеттеры
    }
}
```

после чего, из этих кубиков можно сформировать запрос:

```
String subject = "subj";
String message = "msg";

Request request = new Request(
        new Request.RequestFields(
                new Request.RequestProject("*****"),
                subject,
                message,
                new Request.RequestPriority("Trivial"),
                new Request.RequestIssueType("New Feature")
        )
);


ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request);
System.out.println(json);
```

Разумеется, для крупного проекта, активно взаимодействующего с внешним API,   предпочтительно создать полноценную модель предметной области с Enum-ами, валидацией, иммутабельными классами, где это возможно.

Comment: Спасибо! Супер!